# Why does HTML with poor and improper tag usage still work?

Tags: html, syntax, tags, quirks-mode, error-recovery

The tl;dr version is why does html that doesn't close tags properly still work error free?

I'm learning more and more HTML each day but I'm still quite a beginner. So I don't understand why badly written HTML without properly closing tags still works. I was using an email template for a task at work and was curious about the HTML behind it so I loaded to code into an editor.

I came across 9 separate tags that don't close: `<td> <center> <div> <p> <div> <td> <tr> tbody> <table>` The code starts with an `<html>` tag as it should, but in the `<body>` after a `<table>` and `<tr>`, it starts another `<html> <head>... etc` set of tags. In the two `<style>` tags, they both say say the same thing and have an extra closing brace `li { margin-bottom: 10px; } }`.

When I load just this code into my browser the page still visually appears how it is supposed to. In Firebug though, after the first body tag, it skips table, tr, html, head, and body, and goes straight to just showing the first `<div>`.

Why is it that a webpage (because I'm sure this must be a somewhat common thing out there) that has missing closure tags, extra `<html>` and `<body>` tags, etc still able to function properly?

Comment: Note that html is not xml: It is perfectly legal to skip closing tags on certain elements (eg. `meta`, or ìmg`). Also most user agents apply sophisticated algorithms to auto-correct html content that actually is malformed.

Comment: Google terms: "quirks mode", "tag soup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an application of the [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

> Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others

I'd argue this is an inevitable outcome in a landscape of competing browsers.  If an HTML error prevents a site from working in browser A, but browser B is able to guess a correction, users will tend to use browser B, as A appears to be broken.  This has been going on since Netscape 3 or earlier.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. In regards to the extra `<html> <head> <body>` tags inside the original `<body>`, am I correct in my thoughts that you should never really have this situation appear in your code? @recursive

Comment: @JoeL You're right - badly formed HTML should be considered a syntax error and it _should be_ rejected outright. It's unfortunate that browsers don't do that - this led to a lot of problems over the years when dealing with general HTML content off of the Internet.

Comment: @JoeL:  There's no good reason to produce malformed html, like including multiple `<body>` tags.  The fact that it happens to work shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

Misformed HTML does not work correctly - browsers try to guess the intent of the HTML structure and display whatever the result of the guess is. This is the result of an unfortunate decision to allow poorly-formed HTML to display, rather than rejecting it and forcing the author to fix such problems.

When you see misformed HTML looking correct on the screen, it's not the result of correct behavior: it's the result of a lucky guess on the part of the browser (obviously, a tiny problem is easier to fix by guessing than a massive structural problem that spans the entire HTML structure).

It comes down to treating HTML as content (which it is not), rather than a formal language (which it is): content authors were (and are) considered non-technical people and forcing them to fix problems with "content" was seen too hard a requirement.

Comment: "markup language" is right in the name.  You can't really express any logic in html.  Why would you call it a programming language?  Surely a programming language should be able to add two number together.

Comment: @recursive You're right, it's not for logic. I'll update my answer to say "formal language" instead, since it has strict formal rules that describe whether a piece of HTML is correct or not.

Comment: @recursive The reason I don't want to use "markup language" because of its bad connotation as "describing content". I know it wasn't meant to mean that but over time my experience shows that that's how it's used.